# In Twilio how could I get the usage of only active phones

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, usage-statistics

I was just wondering if there is any endpoint in the Twilio API to get the usage filtered by Active Phone Numbers.

I've been going through the docs but can't seem to find a solution other than checking the calls endpoint for each one of the phone numbers in my account which is not ideal.

If I check the usage endpoint and filter by category phone numbers since the account was opened it says I've had 300 phones so far, but I can't seem to find how many of those are active or not.

**Updated**

Also, is there a way to filter the usage per phone number? For example I'd like to see the usage for a specific phone number but I don't want to call the Calls endpoint I just want the Usage.

Comment: How do you define an "Active Phone Number"?

Comment: For example I provision a phone number, use it for a while and then remove the number from my account. That number would be inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can check how many currently active phone numbers you have with the [Incoming Phone Numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers).

I'm afraid there's no way to separate your [usage records](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records) by phone number within the one account.

However, you can do this by [subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts). If you are trying to measure different users' usage within your system then the best thing to do is to create subaccounts for each of those users. Your main account can still view usage records for all subaccounts, but the subaccounts can also be viewed individually.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: So if I have 100 users each one with a phone number I would need to create 100 subaccounts?

Comment: If that's how you want to access the usage records, then yes.

Comment: Ok, I think It'd be best to be able to filter the usage per phone number instead of having to create a subaccount per phone number. Thanks for your input

Comment: Being able to break down usage by subaccount allows you to group users of your applications with more than one number if you need. For what you're describing, one subaccount per number is the recommended way to use the API for this. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments @philnash but for our scenario is not the best way to do it. We have about 100 subscribers with a twilio account, they give us api access, but each of them have an x amount of phone numbers, we would need to generate sub accounts for each one and that would be very time consuming. That's why filtering the usage by phone number would be the best, but since it's not available I guess will look for a work around

Comment: You can [generate subaccounts via the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts), if that helps?